GPU Memory leak in pytorch
A wired problem in pytorch.
I have two loss, called loss_1 and loss_2. For convenience, I calucate both, but just backward loss_1. Then, It OOM. However, If I backward both loss, Loss_1 and Loss_2, It will be normal.
for epoch_id in trange(last_epoch + 1, args.n_epochs, desc="Epoch"):
        model.train()
        for qids, labels, *input_data in tqdm(train_dataloader, desc="Batch"):
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            bs = labels.size(0)
            for a in range(0, bs, args.mini_batch_size):
                b = min(a + args.mini_batch_size, bs)
                if args.prior_loss:
                    logits, loss_2, _  = model(*[x[a:b] for x in input_data])
                else:
                    logits, _ = model(*[x[a:b] for x in input_data])
                # logits: [bs, nc]
                loss = loss / (b - a)
                if args.prior_loss and epoch_id>args.prior_loss_epoch:
                    loss+=loss_2
                elif args.prior_loss:
                    del loss_2
                loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            scheduler.step()



Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to provide a minimal, reproducible example so that others can reproduce your problem and have a common basis to share their solution with you.
